# How to replace all cells in a column with a number from a list on another sheet?

Tags: excel

I have a list of names on Sheet1.
On Sheet2 I have those same names but column next to the names I have ID's.
Like this:

```
Name |ID
-------
John |1
Sarah|2
```

I'm trying to pull the data from Sheet1 into Sheet3 and replace all matching names with ID's from Sheet2

What I have so far is

```
=(Sheet1!A1)
```

Now I just need to figure out how I can replace with ID from Sheet2

I have tried all kinds of formulas I found on google but none work. How to do it?

Comment: `VLOOKUP` function may be

Comment: ^ Something like `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A1:B3,2, TRUE)` (A1 being the **lookup value**, Sheet2!A1:B3` being the **table array**, 2 being the **return column**, TRUE being an exact match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, copy & paste values for the column in sheet3 that you used `"=(Sheet1!A1)"` so you can have the values it pulled instead of the formula.

Now, assuming:

- The names in sheet3 are in column A and has a header in A1 (i.e. "Name")
- Sheet2 matches the names to the correct ID, has names in Col A, and ID's in Col B
- Names are unique and do not re-occur

Enter the following B2 (directly to the right of the first value):

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B2:$B11,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A2:$A11,0))
```

or

=INDEX(*range that contains desired value*,MATCH(*lookup value*,*range lookup value is in*, *"0" for exact matches*))

I find INDEX/MATCH to not only be easier to remember the syntax, but more useful VLOOKUP in *most* (not all) situations due to its ability to look left of a reference column and ease of use in arrays when there are more lookup values and ranges.